# iOS Swift - How to obtain OAuth 2.0 access token in order to send Firebase Cloud Message?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my iOS app, I'm trying to send a push notification from one device to another using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I am trying to use the Firebase-recommended [v1 HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) (as opposed to the FCM legacy HTTP API). The v1 HTTP protocol requires sending a POST request to the url `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/messages:send` as described in the Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send). However, at the bottom it states that some authorization scopes are required:

[image: Screenshot from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send]

It later explains [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#update-authorization-of-send-requests) that I need to add the OAuth 2.0 access token (with the above scopes authorized) to the header (e.g. "Authorization": "Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA").

But where/how can I generate this access token? I believe the answer lies [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-http-v1-send-requests), but I'm struggling to understand since I'm not that familiar with backend. Is there a way to obtain the token just from the client side using only Swift, or can it only be obtained from a server environment...?

Any insight is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your access token here : https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdc7Z.png)
Click `Authorize APIs` and get your access token!

Comment: It only provides temporary tokens. It's going to expire after an hour (approx). But the solution expected is to get the token programmatically.